# Cluster-aware Tomcat web application

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing

I believe this task is not much exotic, but due to the lack of clustering experience I feel hard to find the answer.
Our web-app performs some background operations by schedule (data querying and transfer). 
Now Tomcat server on which it is running goes clustered. We need only one instance in cluster to perform these background operations, not all.
I see following options:

- The ideal solution would be master/slave model of cluster, where slave instances of Tomcat has our application in inactive status (undeployed). If slave becomes a master, application gets deployed and starts to work. Is it possible ?
- If not, then we need some notifications/events that we can implement listeners for, in order to know when some node starts up / shuts down. We will then programmaticaly make application in first raised node a master, and block unwanted process in other (slave) nodes. Further we will listen to startup / shutdown events from nodes to keep always a single active master. I were looking for such events API in Tomcat but wihout luck so far.

Does anyone have experience with such task ? How did you solve it ?
Thank you.

Comment: could you revise the text? It is a bit hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a master/slave behavior setting in a Tomcat cluster, because I think all nodes need to be equal. But what about using the [Quartz Clustering with JDBC-JobStore](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)? You can define the tasks within a shared database and if a task is triggered, the first available node will execute it. So all nodes in your cluster will have the same behavior while only a singe node will execute the same task at a time:

> "Only one node will fire the job for each firing. ... It won't necessarily be the same node each time - it will more or less be random which node runs it. The load balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of triggers) but favors the same node for non-busy (e.g. few triggers) schedulers."

If a node fails while executing a task the next available node will retry:

> "Fail-over occurs when one of the nodes fails while in the midst of executing one or more jobs. When a node fails, the other nodes detect the condition and identify the jobs in the database that were in progress within the failed node."